# Binding an ObservableCollection to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, observablecollection

Okay, I am brand new to WPF. I am trying to bind a collection to a `DataGrid` control. When I run the program, the cells in the `DataGrid` are blank, even though there is data in the collection.

I have read all of the relevant articles on MSDN -- multiple times. I've searched Stack Overflow with no luck. I've spent a day and a half on this, and am just as confused as I was when I first started. Here is what I have so far.

The XAML for the `DataGrid` control:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,85,0,0" Name="dtaCompilation" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FileName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And here is the class containing my collection:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dtaCompilation.DataContext = Compilation;
    }

    ObservableCollection<CompilationFile> Compilation = new ObservableCollection<CompilationFile>();

    public class CompilationFile : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public CompilationFile(string setPath, string setFile, string setExt)
        {
            this.Path = setPath;
            this.FileName = setFile;
            this.Extension = setExt;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        private string fileName;

        string FileName {
            get { return fileName; }
            set
            {
                fileName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
            }
        }

        string Path { get;  set; }
        string Extension { get;  set; }
    }
}
```

The end result is to have a `DataGrid` that shows only the `FileName` property for each `CompilationFile` object in the `Compilation` collection. If I edit a cell in the DataGrid, the `FileName` property for the relevant object will be updated in the collection. What exactly do I need to do to get this to work with the code above?

Comment: I usually use CollectionViewSource for binding to oc.

Comment: Please show where you are adding values to Compilation.

Comment: ["The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected, private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base implementation."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the properties you want databound to public

```
public string FileName {
        get { return fileName; }
        set
        {
            fileName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
        }
    }

 public string Path { get;  set; }
 public string Extension { get;  set; }
```

Comment: Figures that it would be something that simple. I suppose I assumed that the properties were already public, and that I was not binding the data correctly.

Comment: @Andrew Default member access is `private`, not `public`